# Handle extra form fields in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a `ExtraPerfilType` Symfony2 form with this content (irrelevant info was removed):

```
class ExtraPerfilType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
                ->add('estado', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'CommonBundle:SysEstado',
                    'property' => 'nombre',
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Estado',
                    'empty_value' => 'Seleccione un estado',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'estados'
                    )
                ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
                array(
                    'data_class' => 'Sunahip\UserBundle\Entity\SysPerfil',
                    'intention' => 'extra_user_profile'
                )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'extra_user_profile';
    }

}
```

And this is the function on `BasicDataController.php` that build and display the form:

```
/**
 * @Route("/basicdata", name="basicdata")
 * @Template()
 */
public function basicDataAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $id = $this->getUser()->getId();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:SysPerfil')->findOneBy(array("user" => $id));

    $form = $this->createForm(new ExtraPerfilType(), $entity, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('basicdata-save')));
    return array('entity' => $entity, 'form' => $form->createView());
}
```

In `basicData.html.twig` I have this HTML (irrelevant info was removed):

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id':'form_extra_perfil'}}) }}
    {{ form_label(form.state) }} <span class="oblig">(*)</span>
    {{ form_widget(form.state) }}
    <select class="municipalities" name="municipalities" id="municipalities" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="-1">-- Pick one --</option>
        <span class="oblig">(*)</span>
    </select>
    <select class="parishes" name="parishes" id="parishes" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="-1">-- Pick one --</option>
    </select>
    <select class="city" name="city" id="city" disabled="disabled">
    </select>
    <div><input type="submit" id="form_btttn" value="Guardar"></div>
    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Finally I have this in the function for handle the data and update the records on DB:

```
/**
 * @Route("/basicdata/save", name="basicdata-save")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function guardarAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $id = $this->getUser()->getId();

    var_dump($request->get("extra_user_profile"));
    die();

    ...
}
```

And here is where my problem come since `var_dump` have this:

```
array (size=12)
  'estado' => string '7' (length=1)
  'calle' => string 'asdasd' (length=6)
  'apartamento' => string 'asdasdasd' (length=9)
  'apartamento_no' => string 'asdasda' (length=7)
  'referencia' => string 'sdasdas' (length=7)
  'codigo_postal' => string 'asdasdas' (length=8)
  'fax' => string 'dasdasd' (length=7)
  'telefono_local' => string 'asdasdasd' (length=9)
  'telefono_movil' => string 'asdasdasd' (length=9)
  'correo_alternativo' => string 'sdsad@asd.com' (length=13)
  'sitio_web' => string 'sadasdads' (length=9)
  '_token' => string 'Wsfi7yJCrovMct-yphPuh_XRQcO4VRqBrcK1BZ89-jE' (length=43)
```

Since municipalities, parishes and city are not in the `ExtraPerfilType` form because they are dependant combos and I fill them by hand using jQuery and of course consulting records on DB and they aren't in the request then how I handle them in order to update theirs values on the record? I'm using latest Symfony 2.5.1, any help or advice?

**Request isn't handle right**

After realize how to work with extra fields now the function I wrote for update the record at DB isn't handle `$request` and I don't know where it's failing. This is the function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/basic-data/update", name="basic-data-update")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $id = $this->getUser()->getId();

    $entityProfile = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:SysPerfil')->findOneBy(array("user" => $id));
    $formProfile = $this->createForm(new PerfilType(), $entityProfile);
    $formProfile->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formProfile->isValid()) {
        $municipalities= $em->getRepository('CommonBundle:SysMunicipio')->findOneBy(array("id" => $request->get('municipios')));
        $parishes = $em->getRepository('CommonBundle:SysParroquia')->findOneBy(array("id" => $request->get('parroquias')));
        $city= $em->getRepository('CommonBundle:SysCiudad')->findOneBy(array("id" => $request->get('ciudades')));

        $entityProfile->setMunicipio($municipalities);
        $entityProfile->setParroquia($parishes );
        $entityProfile->setCiudad($city);

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('datos-basicos'));
    }
    else {
        $errors = $this->getFormErrors($formProfile);
    }

    return new JsonResponse(array('status' => true, 'errors' => $errors));
}
```

This is the result:

```
{"status":true,"errors":{"persJuridica":[],"rif":[],"ci":[],"nombre":[],"apellido":[],"user":{"email":[],"password":[],"confirm":[]}}}
```

How do I remove those fields from the request since they are handle in other form?

PS: In some parts the code is in spanish since it's a software requirement sorry for that one I tried to set some parts on english for yours to understand

**I've found the solution**

Nevermind about latest edit, I've found the solution:

```
$builder
        ->remove('persJuridica')
        ->remove('rif')
        ->remove('ci')
        ->remove('nombre')
        ->remove('apellido')
        ->remove('email')
        ->remove('password')
        ->remove('confirm')
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose you want to get `municipalities` value :

In controller you get it buy this :

```
$municipality = $request->get('municipalities');
```

Note that you could add fields to a symfony2 form that are not mapped to an entity

Like this :

```
$builder->add('extra_field_name','extra_field_type', array('mapped' => false)); // the option mapped is set to false
```

This way you could get your extra fields the way you mentioned in your question ( with `$request->get("extra_user_profile"))`)

Comment: Yes, I should that adding the extra field on the type class but then I'll get this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362480/dynamic-choices-causes-this-value-is-not-valid-in-symfony2-forms (unanswered question) anyway what's is the best choice? Doing as I said using `$request` object? My principal concern here is when I want to edit the object the select wont be filled with values from DB

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data this may help in your unanswered questions. if your values have no relation to your db then you could make it simple and use the first approach ( making simple selects without adding them to your form ) like this you will  eliminate the overhead of form validation.